The continuum hypothesis in non-set theoretic foundations
I understand the continuum hypothesis and the fact that it's independent of ZFC, but what about other foundations of math? For example, what does it look like in a type theoretic foundation? Is it still independent?

There exists a well-pointed topos which has a natural numbers object and satisfies the negation of the continuum hypothesis, both externally and also in the internal language, which is a kind of type theory (ref: Mac Lane and Moerdijk Sheaves in Geometry and Logic, Chapter 6, main content and exercises)

@FShrike Isn't this an answer to the question?

@MartinBrandenburg Maybe. I wasn’t so sure that it counts, if it were strong enough for OP. We don’t actually prove or construct the thing in type theory, just notice when we’re done that the topos we are has a kind of type theory attached to it

@FShrike It's a really nice example that I intend to read about, but you are right that I'm looking for something more from first principles.

Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/479510/ch-in-non-set-theoretic-foundations
